# How can I make dynamic text in an animation?

Tags: animation

Is there a way to change text during an animation? Something like a readout that could show distance traveled. And have it displayed on the screen of the animation.

Comment: See here: [Animate string property](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3313/animate-string-property)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Building off the answer in [how to animate string properties](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3335/1112), here's a solution.  You can insert the following code in the Text Editor and hit `Run Script`.

## Example: display current frame

Assuming your text object is called 'Text', this will have it read the current frame:

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
obj = scene.objects['Text']

def recalculate_text(scene):
    obj.data.body = f'Current frame: {scene.frame_current}'

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(recalculate_text)
```

The last line just causes the `recalculate_text` function to be run each time the frame is changed ([more](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_60_6/bpy.app.handlers.html) on Application Handlers).

## Example: distance travelled by object

To have a text showing the distance travelled by 'Cube':

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
obj = scene.objects['Text']

def recalculate_text(scene):
    x = scene.objects['Cube'].location[0]
    obj.data.body = f'Distance in x-direction: {x:.1f} meters'
   
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(recalculate_text)
```

where I've used [Python's string formatting](http://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/inputoutput.html) to make distance only display one decimal place.

## Example: time elapsed

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
obj = scene.objects['Text']

def recalculate_text(scene):
    fps = scene.render.fps / scene.render.fps_base  # actual framerate
    seconds_elapsed = scene.frame_current / fps
    obj.data.body = f'Elapsed time: {seconds_elapsed:.1f} seconds'

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(recalculate_text)
```

[Demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNsDh-VsPNc&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Both Time and distance. Thank you.