# Animation Nodes: Dynamic Text?

Tags: python, animation-nodes, text-object

I am trying to make a stopwatch in Blender 2.79 with Animation Nodes and Cycles renderer.

I have an imported movie strip which is 30 fps, and in the animation nodes I am reading the frame number, then dividing by 30. As I play the strip I can see the number correctly track seconds via a viewer animation node.

I also have a text object. I have this as an overlay in one corner of my video strip when viewed in the video editor. Currently it just reads "0:00:00.00". What I am wondering (since I am new to python on Blender...and fairly new to Blender itself) is what the preferred method would be to bind my text object to be updated from the animation node? I have the decimal time in seconds within nodes, but I just do not know how to copy the information from the nodes to the text object.

Comment: You may see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50653/how-to-switch-different-sequences-of-characters-with-animation-nodes/50675?s=1|7.6035#50675

Comment: You might also want to state if you want to be steered in the right direction or given a complete answer.  You have stated you have nodes presently.  If you show your current work that would improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the text object output node in BAN Blender Animation Nodes.
This is not a tutorial on BAN.

[image]

Comment: I am still digesting this and other answers, but I have not heard of BAN. Is there a tutorial or description URL which might explain this? FYI, I am trying to understand what direction to go to learn this and still get past this automated text editing hole in the road.

Comment: @D.Stimits By BAN he means *B*lender *A*nimation *N*odes. We mostly say AN directly though. Have a look at the documentation, [this](http://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/text/timecode_generator.html) and [this](http://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/text/text_object_output.html) might help you.

Comment: Thank you @AtomicBezierSlinger! This got the job done and I was able to learn what I needed to learn. I now have a stopwatch meeting my requirements :) I am curious about one other thing, how to save the nodes of my animation nodes as if it were a library for import, but I'll add that to a new question rather than here.

Comment: @D.Stimits.  The adventure continues.