# Is it possible to change location based on proximity to another object?

Tags: animation, transforms, text-object, parent

I have two pieces of dynamic text, one of which is parented to the other as they go through various transforms in the animation. Is there a way to drive the location of the second text object based on proximity to the first, so that if values change it still is aligned properly?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.  Are you asking if there's a way to change the alignment of the child object based on how close it is to the parent?  If so, an IK constraint might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @MikeBelanger I would like to keep the **space between** two text objects the same **no matter the contents**.

Comment: So if the parent text object changes the amount of characters in it, the child object updates itself to be just as far away from the parent?

Comment: @MikeBelanger That is it exactly.

Comment: Hmm that's a good question.  Sorry, I don't have a upvote-worthy answer.  Assuming your animating the text using this technique http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7904/how-can-i-make-dynamic-text-in-an-animation  perhaps there's some method of making the child object part of the parent object, and making the child's text into a seperate 'Text Box'?  The Text box 'offset' will be driven by the length of the initial string?  https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/texts/editing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Adjacency**

[image]

Consider a driver in the Delta Location X which associates with the X dimension of the adjacent object.  Suit Location index to needs.

[image]

Image above.  Cube has smaller X dimension.

[image]

The cone is a parent as depicted in the Outliner Window.  The sphere delta location is determined by x dimension of the beveled cube.  The alignment must be taken into consideration.  Here the cube origin is the geometric center, thus the script has the corresponding math.

The blue object represents text.

Comment: Awesome, I'll have to try that!