# How to display the current frame number as part of the open GL render?

Tags: animation, opengl

I'm amazed I can't find anything that displays the current frame which is helpful to study test timing and adjusting and knowing where it went wrong. Ideally I would like to show seconds and minutes and the frame number.

Comment: Place a text object in front of camera: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7904/how-can-i-make-dynamic-text-in-an-animation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable the [Metadata stamping](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/output/metadata.html) in the render output properties. It also works for OpenGL renders.

[image: Metadata panel]

Here is a 720p output example of what it looks like with a bigger font and the default options enabled:

[image: example of the result]

Here's how to find the option in **Cycles Render** (first image) and in **Blender Render**/"Internal" (second image):

[image: location of the option (cycles)] [image: location of the option (internal)]