# Background script only works when BGE player stops

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

I want to run a thread in the background of the BGE, that retrieves accelerometer data from a LoPy, and uses the values to rotate the object.

For now, the code I have can only receive and print the data in the console, however the thread itself only runs when I exit the blender game engine. This is my code:

```py
print("---------------------------------------------")
print("Begin collection")

import serial, threading, keyboard

port = 'COM5'

def acc_data(ser):
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed(' '): 
            print('The script was interrupted!')
            break
        raw = ser.readline().decode("utf-8")
        data = raw.split(",")
        try:
            pitch = float(data[0])
            roll = float(data[1])
            print(str(pitch) + " " + str(roll))
        except:
            print("Only one value read")


def acc_thread():
    acc_data(serial.Serial(port, 115200))


try:
    thread = threading.Thread()
    thread.run = acc_thread
    thread.start()
except:
    print("Unable to connect")

print("End collection")
```

This is the logic editor:

[image]

blender console print data
[image]

Comment: Can you place an image of how this prints when you leave BGE?

Comment: @BlenderBlackened here is the [image](https://imgur.com/xsNm4TN)

Comment: Ok, it's showing on the blender console, and you want this to be displayed somewhere on your screen when you're in BGE? you have considered using UPBGE, the game engine is much developed, it is the same but it is more focused on the game engine

Comment: Do you have a HUD in your project?

Comment: Try this tutorial, maybe it will give you a better idea and help you understand a couple of concepts [Blender Tutorial Car Racing Game - Setting Up a Head-Up Display (HUD) and Using New Dynamic Text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Glzw7FgsFZg)

Comment: [How can I make dynamic text in an animation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8087/58715) [Video Demostration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNsDh-VsPNc&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: @BlenderBlackened What I want to do is take those values and use them to match  the rotation of the object in the BGE with the rotation of the LoPy. I'll take a look to the links you sent me and see if I can make it work. Thx for the help.

Comment: I'm looking for a file I had where I made a tachometer for a motorcycle in bg, it should work for your car, but I still can't find it, I don't remember which of my laptop I did it, but I'm still looking for it

Comment: @BlenderBlackened don't bother, I managed to get it to work, I'll put the explanation bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that you can make the script run in a loop by doing this:

[image]

Which allowed me to remove the thread and the infinite loop from my code:

```py
print("---------------------------------------------")
print("Begin collection")

import serial

port = 'COM5'

def acc_data(ser):
    raw = ser.readline().decode("utf-8")
    data = raw.split(",")
    try:
        pitch = float(data[0])
        roll = float(data[1])
        print(str(pitch) + " " + str(roll))
    except:
        print("Only one value read")


try:
    acc_data(serial.Serial(port, 115200))
except:
    print("Unable to connect")


print("End collection")
```

This is what is printed in the console:

[image]