# Is it possible to selectively burn only certain Metadata into the image?

Tags: rendering

I was wondering if there is any chance of selectively burning metadata into the image. In the newer versions of Blender (I guess since 2.8x) it is possible to burn some metadata into the rendered output. Since I cut all my shots together in Premiere Pro, I make use of almost all metadata provided by Blender. But when I enable the option "burn into image" Blender burns all the metadata into the image.

What I want is to only burn the current frame into the image for example.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do I get you right that you want all _metadata_ you can get in the file, but only the frame burned into the image? At first read I thought you just wanted the one that is selected burned into the image and that is how it works...

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann correct, I mark almost all metadata propertys for export, but I only want the frame to be burned

Comment: I think the only way might be a workaround. Put a text object in your scene, place it where you want it to be displayed, maybe give it a simple emission material so that it's not rendered with any shading. Make it invisible for everything but the camera so the emission doesn't affect the scene. Then let the text display the current frame number, a script can be found in this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8087/99859

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann yeah I thought about something similar, but I was hoping for a more dynamic solution, allowing me quickly to change between visible and non visible metadata.

Comment: You can switch visibilty of the text object on and off, just like any other object.