# How can I access the rotation of an object and dynamically update it as text?

Tags: scripting, text-object

I am new to Blender and Python. I wanted to see if there is a way to grab the rotation value of an object and show it as text. I am trying to export this as a 3D model to other software, so I am also wondering if I export it as a FBX will the numbers still show up as changing.

Comment: Hello ! I can definitely say that the answer to the last part of your question is no. Can you elaborate a bit on your setup ? Do you want the 3D text to change dynamically when the object rotation changes ? Does the object rotation change with user input or via code ?

Comment: @Gorgious I am wanting the 3D text to change dynamically when the object rotation changes. So when the rotation is 50 I want the text to say that the rotation is 50. when its 61 the text to say 61 and so on. As of right now the object rotation changes by using the keyframe animation.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

If you want to get something in Python written in a 3D Text in your scene, see:

[How can I make dynamic text in an animation? - Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8087/53447)

You can get an object's euler rotation via:

```py
bpy.data.objects["NAME OF OBJECT"].rotation_euler
```

### Short introduction to Python and Blender's API and how to discover it by yourself

Let's switch to the scripting workspace to make some experiments:

[image: scripting]

When you want to get a value as python, all you have to do is RMB it and click `Copy Full Data Path`:

[image: Full Data Path]

Then, to test it out, you can paste it into Blender's Python Console:

[image: python console]

```py
>>> bpy.data.objects["Cube"].rotation_euler[1]
0.0
```

The line with `>>>` is a command you entered, and the line after that is what Blender returned as value.

Think of the dots in a command like the `/` in a file path. Each "folder" may contain data that you can querry or edit, or other "folders".

Let's decompose that command:

- `bpy.data.objects["Cube"]` point to the data of the object named "Cube".
- `.rotation_euler` gets its Euler rotation (objects have different rotation systems with different coordinates, so you have to indicate which one you want to access). The different axes values are stored as a list, so you can either get all the values at once from there, or you can ask for a specific element of the list like bellow:
- `[1]` gets you the second value within the list of values contained in `rotation_euler`. Counting starts from zero in programming. So X = 0, Y = 1, Z = 2

Now, let's say you just want to get the full rotation of the object, you could simply write the same command without `[0]`:

```py
>>> bpy.data.objects["Cube"].rotation_euler
Euler((0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 'XYZ')
```

Now, this command works only on the object named "Cube". If you wanted a different object, you could simply replace the name in the command. But more often than not, in scripting we prefer to have make scripts that work without the need to manually tell object names.

An easy way for that is to replace the part pointing to a specific object by a query to the selected object. This kind of information is usually stored under `bpy.context`.
Let's pretend I don't remember what exactly is the command to querry my selection. What I can do is type `bpy.context.selec` and press <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> to have the python console autocomplete, or show the possible things I can get:

[image: autocompletion]

Here you can see "selected_objects" in the list. That sounds like what we want, so let's assemble the full line:

```py
>>> bpy.context.selected_objects
[bpy.data.objects['Cube'], bpy.data.objects['Camera']]
```

As you can see, it didn't just returned the path to our Cube, it also returned the path to my camera which is also selected, separated with a `,` and put them between `[]`. That is a Python list. And it's logical, we asked to get the `selected_objectS`. And that's what will allow you work on multiple objects at once if you want.

Now, if you want to get only one object, you can do as we did with the rotation axes and pick which object's rotation you want to see by adding a `[number]` in front of the `selected_objects`:

```py
>>> bpy.context.selected_objects[0].rotation_euler
Euler((0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 'XYZ')
```

Alternatively, if you want to get all selected object's rotation, you can't just put `.rotation_euler` at the end. What you need to do is tell Python "for each `selected_objects`, show me `rotation_euler`. Which is done by a `for` loop:

```py
>>> for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
...     obj.rotation_euler
...     
Euler((0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 'XYZ')
Euler((1.1093189716339111, 0.0, 0.8149281740188599), 'XYZ')
```

Now, I will skip lengthy explanations because I won't make a full Python tutorial here, but if you wanted to make a reusable script out of this, and make the returned data more readable, you could do this:

```py
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    re = obj.rotation_euler
    objName = obj.name
    rx, ry, rz = round(re[0], 1), round(re[1], 1), round(re[2], 1)
    
    print(f"'{objName}' rotation :  X {rx}  Y {ry}  Z {rz}")
```

You need to enter that in the Text Editor, click the Run button, and you will see the result in Blender's system console (Window > Toggle System Console)

[image: console]

For more information about scripting in Blender:

- [Blender 3.5 Python API Documentation — Blender Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/)
- [3.10.10 Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/)

Comment: Outstanding answer ! I would just avoid overriding the builtin `object` keyword in python, it can have unintended consequences.

Comment: yeah I first missed the part where the OP said he wanted to output stuff as a 3d text object, so i thought a mini introduction to bpy discovery was needed. And by the time i got my mistake, it was already all written and I didn't want it to go to waste x) Good point about `object`, made some changes.